# How to have SQL increase ID by 1 on a column using an insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert multiple rows into SQL. The table contains an external ID column that when using the APP increases this ID by one. The external ID is not the Primary key, but another ID in the table. Currently last external ID is 544. I want to insert 1600 additional rows and have the external ID increase by 1 for every row inserted. I have tried the following, but all of the external IDs end up being 100.

```
INSERT INTO tableA (externalid,tableuiduid) 
VALUES ((select ISNULL(MAX(EXTERNALID) +1, 0)from tableA),newid());
```

I have also tried this, but it ends up inserting a duplicate external ID, as there are gaps in the numbers.

```
INSERT INTO tableA (ExternalID,tableAuid)
VALUES ((select count (externalid) + from tableA),newid());
```

Please let me know what I need to use to have this increase by 1 and not insert a duplicate ID.

Comment: What database platform? In SQL Server you would use an identity column.

Comment: @RagingBull Yeah, but it's also used by MS Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're doing it now, depending on your RDBMS, you can use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (externalid, tableuiduid) 
select ISNULL(MAX(EXTERNALID) + 1, 0), newid()
from tableA;
```

But you'll need to execute that 1600 times.

If you have an auxilliary number table or use a recursive CTE, you could use that to generate 1600 rows at once, but without knowing your RDBMS a precise implementation is very difficult.

You could define the field as an automatically incrementing field or sequence, but I get the impression that that isn't a good idea because you're not always going to be determining what the `externalid` value is.

Comment: Using this still makes all of the external ID s 100.

Comment: @Derick What data type is `externalid`?  And what does `select MAX(EXTERNALID) from tableA` return?

Comment: Datatype = varchar(25) and select returns 99

Comment: @Derick Then... why isn't 100 correct?  Where is 544 coming from?

Comment: 100 is not correct as anytime I do an insert it adds the external ID as 100. When I do an update through the app it will add the external ID as the next number such as 545. Currently the highest external ID in the table is 547.  So not sure why when I run the select statement it returns 99, I would think it would return the last number used. SO if I run it now I would think it would return 547.

Comment: @Derick Because it's a `VARCHAR` field.  `'99'` is alphabetically after `'547'`.  You'd need `MAX(CAST(ExternalID AS Int))`.  SQL Server is already doing implicit typecasting by turning `'99' + 1` into `100` instead of `'991'`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the +1 outside of `ISNULL`. And use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT`.

Try this way:

```
DECLARE @Cnt as int
SET @Cnt = 0

WHILE (@Cnt < 1600)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tableA (externalid,tableuiduid) 
    select ISNULL(MAX(EXTERNALID),0) + 1,newid()
    from tableA
    SET @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
END
```

Comment: Using this still makes all of the external ID s 100.

Comment: @Derick: Edited my answer. Try it now. What is the maximum value in the column `externalid`?

Comment: I tried this as well and it is still 100. Max value using select max(externalid) from table A = 99.   I guess I am trying to find out how the app increases the external ID, but when i use an insert statement it only goes to 100.

Answer (score 0):

First create a sequence.

```
create sequence seq1
   start with 544
   increment by 1
   maxvalue 99999;
```

Then insert.

```
  INSERT INTO tableA (externalid) 
  VALUES (seq1.nextval())
```

Comment: Receive following error when trying to run insert statement.     Cannot find either column "seq1" or the user-defined function or aggregate "seq1.nextval", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: You have to create the sequence first before running the insert query.